# How to draw the bar in the canvas based on time in html5

Tags: javascript, html, css

Let me explain it clearly. I have to draw a bar chart using html5 and i did it. The problem is the bar size has to increase based on the given time. I.e. if i give 30 as value and time as 3. it has increase as 10,20 and have to reach 30 on the 3rd second. I have included the barchart code here.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload=function(){
                var canvas=document.getElementById('mycanvas');
                var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');
                var value=[10,20,30,40,50,90];
                var width=50;
                var currx=30;
                ctx.fillStyle="red";
                for(i = 0; i < value.length; i++)
                {
                    var h=value[i];
                    ctx.fillRect(currx,canvas.height-h,width,h);
                    currx+=width+10;
                }
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="mycanvas" height="400" width="400" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You forgot to state your question.

Comment: Just use setTimeout or setInterval to to redraw your bar every second

Comment: I agree with Musa. All you have to do is have to functions: `update()`, which increments the values and calls `render(), and `render()` which draws it to the screen. You may also want a setup function as well that sets up the initial variables and set the interval.

Comment: @Musa : Here is the fiddle can u help me out i tried it many times. Am not good in html. http://jsfiddle.net/6nXE3/

Comment: @praveensingh you mean javascript?

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs : i can also use javascript or css. But i wont use any other apis like google api.

Comment: @praveensingh I do not think that you will have to

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs : Now only got ur idea. Thanks hope i can be able to do it. bcos am newbie to html. Thanks a lot

Comment: Something like this [Fiddle}(http://jsfiddle.net/6nXE3/2/)

Comment: Can u post it as an answer so that i can able to mark it as the solution for this question. pls post the code here as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload=function(){
                var canvas=document.getElementById('mycanvas');
                var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');
                var value=[180,140,30,340,50,90];
                var width=50;
                var currx=30;
                ctx.fillStyle="red";
                var i = 0;
                var interval = setInterval(function(){
                    if (i == value.length){
                        clearInterval(interval);
                        return;
                    }
                    var h=value[i];
                    ctx.fillRect(currx,canvas.height-h,width,h);
                    currx+=width+10;
                    i++;
                }, 2000);console.log(interval);
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="mycanvas" height="400" width="400" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;">
    </body>
</html>
```